# how do I make a "while" loop that repeats itself if a variable isn't equal to a certain number in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a while loop that repeats itself if let's say var1 isn't equal to 100

example code:

```
import math

var1=1
var2=2
while var1<100:
var1=var1*var2
if var1<100:
print(var1)
else:
while var1(what do I put here ?)100:
var1=var1+var2
print(var1)
```

the code above might be inefficient, but I'd really like to know how you do this

Comment: Not equal is written: `!=`, so this means you want `while var1 != 100` ?

Comment: Could you please put your code in a markdown code block (e.g. ```python \n your code\n ``` and format it properly: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: The first loop won't exit until `var1 >= 100`, so any subsequent check of `var1 < 100` is guaranteed to be false.

Comment: I added this because when running the program, the last number printed was 128, which is above 100

Answer (score 1):

You could either do

```
while not var1 == 100:
    ...
```

Or

```
while var1 != 100:
    ...
```

But the second one is better.

Comment: The second is absolutely better; there's no reason to write the first one.